# Can someone explain how VIEWS & JOIN works in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Okay guys, i'm literally SCREWED. My professor is on indefinite leave and I have an assignment due next Friday which I'm completely lost on. I've entered all my data into my tables and I'm creating the views. Our assignment is to create 5 reports for a business in SQL and transfer them to Excel to create a frontend.

Basically, can someone describe to me how I would I utilise view and joins to create a report for this

Answer (score 1):

A join means you are going to match up columns in two tables that have the same column, and add the data for both tables together, essentially creating one big table. You can create a view by using this code. What that will do is give you one thing to call, the view, and it will contain all of the code from the joins you did to create it, so you don't have to re-code and re-validate every time you want to use those joins. This isn't the place where we can just give you what you'd learn in your course, but I hope that helps.

Example:

```
select *
from tableSales a
join tableStaff b on a.Staff_ID = b.Staff_ID
join tableNext c on b.Column = c.Column (you can also join to table a)
```

This will give you the data from both tables in one place, based on the staff ID. You can then join a column from the tableStaff table to another table and so on.
With this one statement you can run it and see how it puts all the columns into one table. If you put this code into a view, you can then access it. Furthermore, Excel has built in functionality to read the views you have created, and lets you refresh the reports by connecting to the database and then to the view.
Good luck!
Watch out for duplicates!

Comment: Thank you Jswan, Could you explain to me how you join multiple tables to the one?

Comment: Keep adding JOIN references after the first. If you have a view saved, you can treat that view as a table when joining to it (that's pretty basic but you get the idea). you can add a new table (let's call it 'c') and join that to either table a or table b (or both)

Comment: I added to the example